# Openai-api : Tripple "number char" in content

Tags: openai-api

Many times in code samples I found the `###` (tripple number char) used as specific separator. But I can't find any information in `openai` api documentation. Is it unformal? Some kind of legacy from older openai versions?

E.g.

```
"content": "###Areas of learning###\n{areas_of_learning}\n\n###Instructions###\nCategorise the following text to one or more areas of learning.\n{text}\n"
```

Comment: Maybe just a [Markdown heading level 3](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#headings)?

Comment: Users trust that chatgpt understands headings as more important parts of the question and include them into content... Wow...